# How to fix Core Web Vitals FID issue in Asp.Net?

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, seo

I have created an E-commerce based web application in Asp.Net(Backend: Vb) with a BVcommerce tool which is working absolutely fine but due to new guideline of google for page ranking and SEO application has to pass Web Vitals Test so I have changed some of my code and now Largest Contentful Paint (LCP) & Cumulative Layout Shift (CLS) passes with more than 85% percent but when talks come to First Input Delay (FID) it passes only 40% so can you please help me to solve that.

I have also tried to remove all homepage content(Images, Menu and Footer) but still, the results are the same as earlier.

In my application, there is all page load mechanism because it created 4years ago so it creates an issue.  I also attach result image here.[image: Web Vitals Test Result]

Can anyone have an idea about this then please let us know.

Comment: My site passes in Desktop but failed in Mobile due to the same result. In Desktop FID is 3ms but when turns into Mobile it is around 225ms so it fails. It creates a major challenge for me. If anyone has idea then please let me know.

Comment: I believe FID issues can relate to a web page running long running JavaScript tasks that stop the page responding to users. The Chrome developer tools Performance tab can help you analyse long running JavaScript tasks.

Comment: Thanks, @TonyMcCreath Actually my application is built near 2017 and it is a pure Asp.Net application and there is only a jquery application and it is used for hiding/show or animation rest of the features are done using Postback that we follow years ago. In this case what we have to do that? Your little help can change the performance application.

Answer (score 0):

First Input Delay (FID) is a pure real user metric and measures the delta between when an input event is received and when the main thread is next idle to execute that event, hence the main thread blocking time is directly proportional to this metric score

The [web vitals](https://web.dev/optimize-fid/) suggests some good optimizations to improve this score:

- Break up Long Tasks
- Optimize your page for interaction readiness
- Use a web worker
- Reduce JavaScript execution time

It all goes to the main thread optimization at the end - an approach [idle until urgent](https://philipwalton.com/articles/idle-until-urgent/) is the best in terms of optimizing the performance, hence the lighthouse score. Try reducing non-critical network requests for resources (CSS and JavaScript files) loading over the main thread and instead load them asynchronously

Image heavy pages are better optimized by determining when the media item has entered the user’s viewport and fire an event, this is achievable by [Intersection Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API), hence a lazy loading methodology used by modern mobile first frameworks for better user experience